# Find a pattern3 that occurs between pattern1 and pattern2 and return all the lines between pattern1 and pattern2 using sed or awk

Tags: awk, sed, grep

=============The File Starts here=============

**pattern1:**

patterna

patternb

patternf

patternc

patternd

patterne

**pattern2**

**pattern1:**

patterna

patternb

pattern_pat

patternc

patternd

patterne

**pattern2**

**pattern1:**

patterna

patternb

patternf

patternc

patternd

patterne

**pattern2**

**pattern1:**

patterna

patternb

pattern_pat

patternc

patternd

patterne

**pattern2**

**pattern1:**

patterna

patternb

patternf

patternc

patternd

patterne

**pattern2**

=============The File ends here=============

now the pattern i want to search is is pattern_pat; I need to print all the line between pattern1 and pattern2 that contains pattern_pat. like following

=============OutPut File=============

**pattern1:**

patterna

patternb

pattern_pat

patternc

patternd

patterne

**pattern2**

**pattern1:**

patterna

patternb

pattern_pat

patternc

patternd

patterne

**pattern2**

I am new to awk and sed. so, any help regarding this would be great

Answer (score 1):

gawk

```
awk -vRS='pattern1:' '/pattern_pat/&&/pattern2/{printf "%s %s",RT,$0}' file
```

sed

```
sed -n '/pattern1:/{:a;N;/pattern2/!ba;/pattern_pat/p}' file
```

Comment: In the awk solution there is no mention of `pattern2` which may lead to false positives.

Answer (score 0):

Using awk (portable, should work with any POSIX awk):

```
$ awk ' f{s=s ORS $0}; /pattern1/{s=$0; f=1; g=0}; f && /pattern_pat/{g=1}; f && g && /pattern2/{print s; f=0}' file
pattern1:
patterna
patternb
pattern_pat
patternc
patternd
patterne
pattern2
pattern1:
patterna
patternb
pattern_pat
patternc
patternd
patterne
pattern2
```

This version uses two variables as flags.  Variable `f` is true (`1`) when we are inside a pattern1...pattern2 group.  Variable `g` is true (`1`) if we have seen `pattern_pat` within this group.  Whenever we reach pattern2, we print the group if both `f` and `g` are true.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is working as expected. What if there are forward slashes in the search pattern??

Comment: @rajaswisaka If `pattern1` contains a `/`, then replace `/pattern1/` with `\|pattern1|` or with `\#pattern1#` or choose another character that is not in `pattern1`.